# Can a percentage be lets say 0.172% even after multiplying it by 100?

Tags: arithmetic

Can a percentage be lets say 0.172% even after multiplying it by 100?
The reason is, in my calculation i did the following; (4.3601/2329.475495)x100 giving me the above answer. Is that correct or am i in the wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated David P, for more information about the site and how to ask questions, you can check out the [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq). Is your question just about whether the calculation is right or wrong (it is wrong, with the numbers you give on your second line the result of the operation is 0.187, rounded)? Otherwise, yes, a percentage can be as close to zero as you can imagine because it is bounded between 0 and 100 and continuous on that interval.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, (4.3601/2329.475495)x100 is calculating what percentage 4.3601 is of 2329.475495, which is 0.18717%. As a quick sanity check you could, round the numbers off to 4 and 2300, then note that 1% of 2300 is 23 so 4 is way smaller than 1% of 2300.

Perhaps you're confused because you're used to calculation like 436.01/2329.475495 = 0.18 and that means 18%. But 0.18 doesn't mean 18% of something, it's 18% in this case because you are calculating what percentage 436.01 is of 2329.475495. Context is everything.

"Percent" literally means "per 100", so depending on what you're calculating you can have percentages larger than 100, even. For example, if you sold 150 widgets last year and 300 this year, that's a 100% increase (100/100 *more*) but you could also say that this year's sales are 200% (200/100 *times*) of last year's sales.